# MySQL Slow query for 'COUNT'

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, sql-tuning

The following query takes 0.7s on a 2.5Ghz dual core Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise when run over a 4.5Gb MySql database. `sIndex10` is a varchar(1024) column type:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM e_entity
WHERE meta_oid=336799 AND sIndex10 = ''
```

An `EXPLAIN` shows the following information:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: e_entity
type: ref
possible_keys: App_Parent,sIndex10
key: App_Parent
key_len: 4
ref: const
rows: 270066
extra: Using Where
```

There are 230060 rows matching the first condition and 124216 rows matching the clause with `AND` operator. `meta_oid` is indexed, and although `sIndex10` is also indexed I think it's correctly not picking up this index as a `FORCE INDEX (sIndex10)`, takes longer. 
We have had a look at configuration parameters such as `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and they look correct as well.

Given that this table has already 642532 records, have we reached the top of the performance mysql can offer? Is it at this point investing in hardware the only way forward?

Comment: You have  'possible_keys: App_Parent,sIndex10' wht yu don't have meta_oid ?   . have you proper index on this column?  eventually show your table schema

Comment: `App_Parent` is the index name for the `meta_oid` column

Comment: A small performance gain might be achieved if app_parent covered BOTH columns

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE meta_oid=336799 AND sIndex10 = ''
```

begs for a *composite* index

```
INDEX(meta_oid, sIndex10)  -- in either order
```

That is *not* the same as having separate indexes on the columns.

That's all there is to it.

[*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: How about the queries that use `meta_oid` without querying `sIndex10`?

Comment: They can use that index, too (assuming the given order).  Queries using only sIndex10 cannot.  The Cookbook says "`WHERE aaa = 123 AND ...`: an INDEX _starting_ with `aaa` is good", etc.

Comment: This didn't make any difference

Comment: If most of the rows have `sIndex10 = ''`, then my suggested index won't help much.

Comment: 53% of the records matching `meta_oid` also have `sIndex10 = ''`

Answer (score -1):

One thing I alway do is just `count(id)` since `id` is (nearly) always indexed, counting just the id only has to look at the index.

So try running and see if it performs any better. You should also add `SQL_NO_CACHE` when testing to get a better idea of how the query performs.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(id) FROM e_entity
WHERE meta_oid=336799 AND sIndex10 = ''
```

Note: This is probably not the complete answer for your question, but it was too long for just a comment.

Comment: Thanks but this made no difference

Comment: `SQL_NO_CACHE` bypasses the Query cache, which, if ON, could give very fast timings for _repeated_ queries.

Comment: `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NULL`.  That is _rarely_ what you want, so `COUNT(*)` is the _usual_ way to write it.  No, the index is irrelevant because the `WHERE` clause is what needs the index.